# Swift iOS -func getting called in loop in playground won't run

Tags: ios, swift, loops, break, swift-playground

I'm using Swift 4.2 Xcode 10.1

In playground I run a loop and when a certain condition is met I exit the loop. Before I use `break` I call a function to print something but I cannot seem to call the function inside in loop because it says it cannot identify the function.

What's the problem here?

```
let arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for num in arr {

    if num == 7 {
        done()
        break
    }
}

func done() {
    print("done")
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know Swift, but the function definition (or at least a declaration) may need to come before it can be called.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Your right, in a regular iOS project that isn't the case. I guess Playground is different. Post your answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: The error will show up when the definition of done is below its call but the playground still executes normally.

Comment: @Palle why is it in a regular Xcode project I can define function anywhere and call it wherever I want to but inside Playground I have to declare it first then call it later?

Comment: I'm hesitant to post an answer when it was a stab in the dark guess. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24596870/3000206) seems to be a loose potential dupe target though. The first answer seems to answer this question here. `"However, when code is executed linearly, such as in Playground, we do not have this initialization so it is not possible to call a function before it's declaration for the reasons previously stated (the compiler is unaware of the function)."`

Comment: @Carcigenicate I understand your hesitation but regardless it's a stab in the dark that was 100% correct. I know how to program well but I'm so used to not having to do it this way in a real project that it threw me off. The next dev who comes along who is just learning might run into the same problem and be mystified. Your answer was simple, straight to the point, and most importantly it worked. I think you should post if anything just to help the next individual who comes along.

Comment: Swift Playgrounds are fine with it, but Xcode's error checker is not. The code that you posted works 100% fine in a playground. The issue does not appear in a normal project because there, Swift files are not executed from top to bottom, but instead lazily. Global variables are only created once they are needed, which also leads to the restriction that you cannot call functions directly at top level scope. The only exception to this rule is a main.swift file that you may use as an entry point to your executable.

Comment: @Palle thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Carcigenicate the question has been marked as a duplicate. Thanks for the help and Happy Holidays!

Comment: In honest, the comments here are more helpful than the duplicate post.